# is it possible to define an unevaluated symbol in sympy?

Tags: python, expression, sympy

I have a list of symbols in sympy:

```
x,y,z = symbols(["x","y","z"])
_symbols = [x,y,z]
```

I need to use these symbols in some algorithmically generated expressions, and these expressions must not be evaluated because I'm using them as excercises.
Is there a method to prevent evaluation by defining these symbols as UnevaluatedExpr? I was thinking as something as

```
map(UnevaluatedExpr, _symbols)
```

but this does not affect the output, as `x+x` gives anyway `2x`.
Also something along the lines of

```
for symbol in _symbols:
   symbol = UnevaluatedExpr(symbol)
```

does not work.

EDIT: I noticed that there is a somewhat weird behavior of `UnevaluatedExpr` (at least for me), namely

```
UnevaluatedExpr(x)**0
```

gives `1`. I would have expected simply `x**0` as output, since `x` could be `0` and in that case it's not true that the result is `1`.

Comment: UnevaluatedExpr prevents evaluation for the objects it contains. Outside, UnevaluatedExpr behaves as an ordinary object, so when raised to the power of zero, it returns 1.

Answer (score 3):

Creating your expressions in an `evaluate(False)` context might be what you want:

```
>>> with evaluate(False):
...  x + x
... 
x + x
```